# Call method of a component in directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I defined a directive iCheck and I want to call a method in a component when I click on radio button ... 
My directive : **directive.ts**

```
declare var jQuery: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[icheck]'
})

export class IcheckDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-aero',
      radioClass: 'iradio_square-aero'
    }).on('ifChecked', function(event) {
      if (jQuery('input').attr('type') === 'radio') {
        // I want to call my method "selectType() of my component.ts ();
      }
    })
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    return;
  }
}
```

**folder.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-folders',
  templateUrl: './folders.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./folders.component.css']
})
export class FoldersComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router)

   selectType(){ ==> Method that I want to call
    alert();
    console.log("Ici");
  }
..}
```

My html file **folder.component.html** where I use my directive in a input

```
<input type="radio" icheck name="type" [(ngModel)]="type"value="OUT"> OUT
```

So how can I call method "selectType()" when I click a radio button ?

Comment: check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44537404/2545680)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways how you can do that:

1. Inject the parent component instance and call the method directly on it
2. Define output event for the directive and bind to it from the parent component.

#### Injecting parent component

```
export class IcheckDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private parentCmp: FoldersComponent) {
    const self = this;

    jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).iCheck({
        ...
    }).on('ifChecked', function(event) {
      if (jQuery('input').attr('type') === 'radio') {

        // I want to call my method "selectType() of my component.ts ();
        this.parentCmp.selectType('value');
      }
    })
```

#### Using output event

Define output for the `IcheckDirective` and then bind to it from the `file.component`:

```
export class IcheckDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @Output() callParentMethod = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    const self = this;

    jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).iCheck({
       ...
    }).on('ifChecked', function(event) {
      if (jQuery('input').attr('type') === 'radio') {

        // I want to call my method "selectType() of my component.ts ();
        self.callParentMethod.next('value');
      }
    })
  }
```

And then inside the template:

```
<input type="radio" icheck name="type" (callParentMethod)="selectType($event)"  [(ngModel)]="type"value="OUT"> OUT
```

Comment: Thx for answer .. I tried the 2 way == 1 - I got error "ERROR Error: No provider for FoldersComponent! " and the second "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined" in my console google chrome

Comment: @user1814879, I updated the second approach, try it. You need to bind `this`, I used `self` variable for it. For the first approach, show the template  of `FoldersComponent` in your question

Comment: so did it work with `self`? I added `const self = this;` on top of the function

Comment: what is this syntax `**icheck**`?

Comment: I tried self ==> and I have a mark error : "Property 'callParentMethod' does not exist on type 'IcheckDirective'."

Comment: It is not not **icheck**, it is ichek (I do mistake when written) ==> It is the name of my directive

Comment: sorry, I don't understand you. Try figure out the problem yourself. The solution I showed should work. And again, what are these stars`**icheck**`?

Comment: I want to say that *icheck* is the name of my directive  `@Directive({
  selector: '[icheck]'
}) `

Comment: so why is it relevant?

Comment: I just wanted to put it font weight bold when I written.. Sorry

Comment: okay, I edited your qutestion and removed `**`. Try figure out where the problem is or ask a separate **more specific question**

Comment: Thx so much .. But for the firs solution, why I got error "ERROR Error: No provider for FolderComponent " ?

Comment: I don't know, I'd have to see a working plunker with the error to understand that

Answer (score 2):

**you can create EventEmitter in directive and whenever you emit it call components function:**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[icheck]'
})

export class IcheckDirective implements AfterViewInit {
   @Output('icheck') callComponentFunction: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmmiter<any>;

jQuery('#radioBtn').change(function (){
            if (jQuery('#radioBtn').attr("checked")) {
                this.callComponentFunction.emit();
            } else {

            }

   ngAfterViewInit(): void {

   }
}
```

and html:

```
<input type="radio" #radioBtn (icheck)="here goes component function you want to call" name="type" [(ngModel)]="type"value="OUT">
```

**if you want just to call function when radio state changes just use jQuery in your component there is no need of directive**

HTML: `<input type="radio" #radioBtn [(ngModel)]="type"value="OUT">`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-folders',
  templateUrl: './folders.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./folders.component.css']
})
export class FoldersComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

 jQuery('#radioBtn').change(function (){
        if (jQuery('#radioBtn').attr("checked")) {
            this.selectType()
        } else {

        }
 });


  selectType() { ==> Method that I want to call
    alert();
    console.log("Ici");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for reply but I got mark error at line @Output ==> `"Multiple markers at this line
- In the class "IcheckDirective", the directive output property "callComponentFunction" should not be renamed.Please, consider the following use "@Output() callComponentFunction = new EventEmitter();"
- '(' expected." `

Comment: Yes, my method is loaded first time when I refresh my page but when I click on radio button the method is not called .. have an issue ?

Comment: @user1814879 it loads first time cause I added this.callComponentFunction.emit() in ngAfterViewInit and it will be called once when directive loads

if you want just to call function from component when radio button state changes just add with change listener on radio button there is no need of directive

Comment: OK thx so much, but I need this directive for other things and custom radio button ...

Comment: I wil search an other issue, I try to use JQuery but method is not called .. I dont know why...

Comment: radio button has checked parameter try to bind it and check this link: https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/ng2-binding-radiobutton-lists/

Answer (score 0):

> "selectType()" when I click a radio button

Bind to the `click` event on the input.

## More

Angular docs on the subject : https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: Ok, bind to the clik like this : `<input type="radio" **icheck**  (click)="selectType()" name="type" [(ngModel)]="type"value="OUT"> OUT` ?? It is my problem, because I tried it but I can not access to method ..

Comment: And when I add in directive the method like : `if (jQuery('input').attr('type') === 'radio') {
        selectType();  ==> Error : Cannot find name 'selectType'.
      }`